# How to convert large JSON to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a 4gb json file I need to convert it to csv I tried the following code:

```
import json
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(10**9)

With open('name.json') as json_file:
    jsondata = json.load(json_file)
 
data_file = open('name.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)
 
count = 0
for data in jsondata:
    if count == 0:
        header = data.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csv_writer.writerow(data.values())
 
data_file.close()
```

Tried many variants of the same code. Always got error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 3756)`

Need code that reads json line by line and writes data to csv

UPD: Example of three lines from this file on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2vjdAhEG)

Comment: You may get an answer to your problem here : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256304/how-convert-a-very-large-json-response-of-a-web-service-into-csv-using-python>

Comment: This isn't a valid JSON file anyway but multiple JSON objects joined in a single file. Try to iterate over each line, feed the line into the JSON parser and extract the wanted information to the CSV file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Can I have a little more detail?

Comment: To which of the steps I mentioned?

Comment: "Try to iterate over each line, feed the line into the JSON parser and extract the wanted information to the CSV file."

Comment: These are the three steps needed. Better try it yourself first and ask here if you have a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Butscher alluded to in a comment, you **probably** have a JSON Lines file: multiple valid JSON objects line-after-line.  I say probably because your description of the problem and the error codes points to JSON Lines, but the (formatted) JSON in the pastebin link has been indented and therefor isn't "lines" anymore.

Still, as Michael was saying, you can open the file like normal, iterate over lines, and load each line (as a string):

```py
f_in = open("input.json")
for line in f_in:
    line_data = json.loads(line)
```

From there you can decide how to get that into your CSV, maybe something like:

```py
    data = line_data["data"]
    writer.writerow([data["id"], data["discount"]])
```

Here's a complete suggestion:

```py
import csv
import json

writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))

f_in = open("input.json")
for i, line in enumerate(f_in):
    line_data = json.loads(line)
    meta = line_data["meta"]
    data = line_data["data"]

    if i == 0:
        writer.writerow(list(meta.keys()) + list(data.keys()))
    writer.writerow(list(meta.values()) + list(data.values()))
```

Given this input JSON Lines:

```json
{"meta": {"type": "order"}, "data": {"id":  107042415, "discount":  330, "personCount":  3}}
{"meta": {"type": "order"}, "data": {"id":  107042785, "discount":  0, "personCount":  2}}
{"meta": {"type": "order"}, "data": {"id":  107042866, "discount":  0, "personCount":  1}}
```

I get this CSV:

```
type,id,discount,personCount
order,107042415,330,3
order,107042785,0,2
order,107042866,0,1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read JSON as a Pandas DataFrame and save the loaded DataFrame as CSV.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_json(path_or_buffer)
df.to_csv(output_path)
```

You can refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html for complete documentation.

This will work as long as JSON is having no syntax errors.

Comment: How can I fix my json file?
Or is it better to try reading it line by line and extracting the right data and writing it to csv?

Comment: You can't read JSON line-by-line as JSON is read as data blocks between braces and square brackets.
If there's any syntax error, you can check for any missing symbols such as commas, square brackets, or brace in the file.

Comment: Are you suggesting removing '', []()'' from the file?

Comment: I am suggesting to evenly match all the brackets as if there there is a syntax error in JSON, that might be because of unevenly matched brackets in the data.

Comment: @MohitGoyal, why did you post an answer that doesn't work just to tell OP they have to do something else?

Comment: @ZachYoung, this solution will work as long as the JSON file is fine. The user has posted 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError' as well, which means there may be some issue with the file itself.

Comment: @MohitGoyal, it’s not JSON, it’s (probably) JSON Lines. There’s nothing to fix.

Comment: Alright @ZachYoung, thanks for the clarification, everything makes sense that way.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(10**9)

# Open the CSV file for writing.
data_file = open('name.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

# Flag to indicate whether the header row has been written to the CSV file.
header_written = False

# Open the JSON file for reading.
with open('name.json', 'r') as json_file:
    for line in json_file:
        # Parse the JSON data for the current line.
        data = json.loads(line)

        # Write the header row if it hasn't been written yet.
        if not header_written:
            csv_writer.writerow(data.keys())
            header_written = True

        # Write the data row.
        csv_writer.writerow(data.values())

data_file.close()
```

Can you try this?